# Is it possible to mock the result of a private method and at the same time obtain coverage in sonar or jacoco?

Tags: java, junit, java-8, mockito, powermock

I need to test a method which calls another private method, the problem is not to try to mock the result that the private method returns, but to do so not to obtain the coverage of jacoco or sonar. I tested with Powermock, with EasyMock but when using a spy, when use an spy the test is not covered by sonar or jacoco. The private method and the public method that make the call are at the same class.

Situation to test:

```java
public class ClassOne {

    private Object methodOne () {
        .....
        return object;
    }

    private Object mehodTwo () {
        return Object name = mehtodOne ();
    }
}
```

Test example:

```
package foo.bar;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(VlcPlayerMinimal.class)
public class VlcPlayerMinimalTest {

  @Test
  public void getVlcRcStatusTest() {
    VlcPlayerMinimal vlcPlayerSpy = PowerMockito.spy(new VlcPlayerMinimal());
    try {
      PowerMockito.doReturn("{status: stopped, id: 2}").when(vlcPlayerSpy, "executeGetRequest", Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
      String vlcRcStatus = vlcPlayerSpy.getVlcRcStatus();
      System.out.println(vlcRcStatus);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      fail("Unexpected exception thrown.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your classes and your test example don't really match; if you want a proper answer, we need to at least be able to tell what it is that is being tested. It does look like the tested class is `VlcPlayerMinimal`, in which case you don't want to mock it at all.

Comment: You should not be mocking the private method. Instead mock any external call in that method. Needing to mock an entire private method suggests an issue with design.

Comment: You really shouldnt be mocking private methods.  One of the points of OO is that an object has a public interface that allows clients (other objects) to interact with it, the interface is a contract that defines what services the object provides.  No client should need to know or care about the implementation details of those services.  Think of a Object that offers a sort method, the client shouldnt know or care how the sort is implemented.  Personally I would avoid the use of PowerMock, for me its an indicator that I have failed in my design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Pick one or the other.

What would such "coverage" even prove? You are not actually covering it. Code coverage is a metric to help you identify spots that are not well tested, not one that you should try to trick into appearing higher than it really is.